# Integrating Spring Security SAML module with CAS

Tags: spring-security, saml, cas, spring-saml, service-provider

Is it possible to use Spring Security SAML module for enabling SAML 2.0 Service Provider functionality with CAS? Native SAML support in CAS does not support this. We have a web application which already uses CAS for authentication and now there is a requirement to enable SAML SP and IdP Initiated federated SSO into this application. [CASShib](https://code.google.com/p/casshib/wiki/CASShibExplained) makes this possible but we would have to use Shibboleth in addition to CAS and there are also some issues with CASShib.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Shibboleth as your SAML Idp, you can use CAS for authenticating users using this method: https://github.com/Unicon/shib-cas-authn2

Comment: No, implementing IdP functionality is not the case. IdP is outside our organization and we only have to implement SAML Service Provider (i.e. SP and IdP Initiated SSO) functionality. We already have CAS in place for our internal SSO / authentication for the app. Now the question is that is it possible to implement SSO federation capability with CAS and Spring Security SAML.